# Cannot import all txt file data

Tags: c++, text, import

I have a problem with importing some data from txt file.

Formatted file data in .txt file is:

( int int double ) e.g. ( 16 21 18.0 )

I have created a function to get data from file and it works but it just gives me the first line (i. e. the first Reading object) then it stops with return 0, with no errors. I guess I have a problem with the input loop but I cannot understand which issue is. I should import all the 50 values stored in the txt file (in 50 lines and one column).
Thank you in advance.

Header3.h

```
#pragma once

struct Reading
{
    int day, hour;
    double temperature;
    char ch1, ch2;
    Reading();
    Reading(char c1, int d, int h, double t, char c2);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Reading& r);   // Setting helper input function
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<Reading>& r);  // Setting helper output function
void vec_import(vector<Reading>& v);   // Read data from txt file
```

temp_stats.cpp (header3's source file)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Header3.h"

void vec_import(vector<Reading>& v)
{
    string iname;
    cout << "Type input filename: ";
    cin >> iname;

    ifstream ist{ iname };
    if (!ist) error("Cannot read from filename ", iname);

    while (true)
    {
        Reading r;
        ist >> r;
        if (!ist) break;
        v.push_back(r);
    }
}

Reading::Reading()
    :ch1{ ' ' }, day{ 0 }, hour{ 0 }, temperature{ 0 }, ch2{ ' ' } {};

Reading::Reading(char c1, int d, int h, double t, char c2)
    :ch1{ c1 }, day{ d }, hour{ h }, temperature{ t }, ch2{ c2 } {};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Reading& r)
{
    int d, h;
    double t;
    char c1;
    char c2;

    is >> c1;
    switch (c1) 
    {
    case '(':
        break;
    default:
        break;
        return is;
    }

    is >> d >> h >> t;

    is >> c2;
    switch (c2)
    {
    case ')':
        break;
    default:
        break;
        return is;
    }

    r = Reading(c1, d, h, t, c2);

    return is;

}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<Reading>& r)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i)
    {
        return os << r[i].ch1 << " " << r[i].day << " " << r[i].hour
            << " " << setprecision(1) << fixed << r[i].temperature
            << " " << r[i].ch2 << endl;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
// Temperature Reading 2.0.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Header3.h"


int main()
{
    Reading r;
    vector<Reading> v;
    vec_import(v);
    cout << v;

    keep_window_open();

    return 0;
}
```

Txt file:

[image: Txt source file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `operator<<()`. You are returning from the loop straight away, so it only prints one value. The fix:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<Reading>& r)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i)
    {
        os << r[i].ch1 << " " << r[i].day << " " << r[i].hour
            << " " << setprecision(1) << fixed << r[i].temperature
            << " " << r[i].ch2 << endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I am dealing from few time with helper functions and I was not able to set it properly.